# React Hooks: is rendering always completed after setState + setTimeout?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Disclaimer: I do not consider the following approach as a good practice. Likely I may or must use `useEffect` instead, but I still want to evaluate the correctness of existing code.

In the context of hooks and functional components, is the following assumption correct?

```
{
    setState(newValue);
    setTimeout(() => {
       //Here code expects that re-rendering of all components affected by changing state has been completed.
    }, 0);
}
```

Can I be sure that re-rendering has been completed after `setTimeout` or it is not guaranteed?

1. Is this assumption correct for the current React version? If no, is there a specific behavior breaking it?
2. Can it be affected by upcoming React changes?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't guaranteed. In order to guarantee that your state has changed you will need to use `useEffect` like this

```
useEffect(() => {
   // do something now that state has changed
}, [state])
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a specific reason why it isn't so, or an example showing that?

Comment: According to the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) "If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think of useEffect Hook as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount combined." So it fires when the component updates, guaranteeing the state has changed.

Comment: I'm familiar with `useEffect`, it's a good solution, but my question is pragmatic: given that I already have code written using `setTimeout` way, are there any caveats or edge cases when it does not work in the described way?

Comment: Ah, well I guess the caveat here would be if the state ever took longer than 0 seconds to change. Then your code inside the `setTimeout` could be using stale state.

So no, you can't be sure. And you'll probably want to refactor to be safe.

Comment: @AlDuncanson that's not correct. `setTimeout` with a 0 second delay does not mean 0 seconds. It means a minimum of zero seconds, with no maximum time whatsoever. It just means that this callback will be pulled from the queue the next time the stack is completely cleared. Since the callback is put on the queue after the state update is requested, if all the state is updated synchronously, setTimeout would guarantee that the re-render is done. Just keep in mind since closure values are captured, using any state value there will always be stale. So: this is a hack, use `useEffect`.

Comment: Right, The `0` is the delay: *time in milliseconds , the timer should wait before the specified function or code is executed*, which isn't guaranteed. And yes my answer is to use `useEffect`.

Comment: @AlDuncanson, JavaScript is single threaded (ignoring web workers).  A setTimeout of zero will not interrupt current execution to run the scheduled function.  If all of React's state processing is done synchronously (and this is the unresolved question), then all the synchronous code must finish before the JS Engine pulls the function scheduled with setTimeout(...,0) off the event queue and onto the stack.  So the question really boils down to whether React internals also use setTimeout(), or whether we can count on all the state updates to be handled in one event cycle.